# Export rendered figures to separated images or documents

Tags: floats, luatex

I'm looking for a way to export all the figures from document as a separated files.

Something like calling `exportfigures foo` that will create all `foo1..n.png`'s from `foo.tex`

I've noticed that there was lot of similar questions but focused on creating separated documents per figure. I don't want it. I want to **extract** figures out of the root document.

One solution I see is to somehow obtain coordinates of the figure corners, maybe by placing some markers there , then passing it to image magic to crop out the desired fragment.

Comment: Do you mean pass `\begin{figure} ...\end{figure}` to `fig001.tex`,  for instance? Manually search, select and save as ... or maybe automatically with an editor or some script automatically, but that seem a bit off-topic here.

Comment: @Fran rather each fighure to figure png, svg, or pdf. When exported to tex, it will not be trivial to typeset it in the same way as in the origina document